# How to get the current date and time to a certain format in python for GMT

Tags: python, python-3.x

What would be a good approach to getting the current date and time in the format below?

```
Mon, 25 Jul 2016 16:36:07 GMT
```

The date format must be exactly as per the HTTP-date header specifications - RFC 7231

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, is this is a good approach?

```
from wsgiref.handlers import format_date_time
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime

now = datetime.now()
stamp = mktime(now.timetuple())
date_header = format_date_time(stamp)
print(date_header) # --> Thu, 27 Jun 2019 13:17:23 GMT
```

Could there be any issues if the code is run in different geographies, does this even matter?